# CompilerParameters add Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json.net, csharpcodeprovider

I have the below script that uses CSharpCodeProvider and adds necessary system libraries. I've come into a situation where I need to include the Newtonsoft.Json.dll for the compiled program. Unfortunately, even though the dll is in the bin folder, I get

`Error (CS0006) Newtonsoft.Json.dll could not be found`

Any ideas would be helpful for me and others who may have the same problem.

```
string code = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(Code.code));
CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Net.Http.dll");
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Newtonsoft.Json.dll");
CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);
if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Error ({0}): {1}", error.ErrorNumber, error.ErrorText));
    }
    string badResult = sb.ToString();
    return badResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Newtonsoft is not registered in the GAC.

The compiler is saying it can't find the assembly, so have you tried giving it the full path to the Newtonsoft DLL?

```
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(@"c:\somepath\Newtonsoft.Json.dll");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this sounds like it could be successfully. Although, I'm unable to test and verify this as this is deployed into Azure as a Web API.

Comment: How about passing a relative path instead then?